# Click on item in android ListActivity not working

Tags: android, imageview, listactivity, listadapter

I have ListActivity with custom ArrayAdapter and following layout for list items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:paddingTop="5dip"
android:paddingBottom="5dip" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="48dip"
    android:layout_height="48dip" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="24.5sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white" 
        android:textSize="12sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

My problem is that, I am unable to click any of the list items. What I've tried so far is
setting `focusable`, `clickable` to `false` (which I found might help) to my ImageView
but, unfortunately, problem remains. Please help, this has been bugging me all day. Thank you.

EDIT: OK, so William's answer helped my out with this one, only problem now is that click on item doesn't highlight it, when I change background colour to black (by setting new theme in manifest for this list activity).
This is my custom style for activity theme `<style name="ContentsListTheme">
        <item name="android:background">@color/black</item>
    </style>` from `res/values/styles/` folder.

To make it clear, once again, default ListActivity background colour is white. I want it black. When I apply the style from above, list activity item highlighting when clicked is disabled. How can I enable it again, to the default highlighting colour?

Answer (score 1):

In your `oncreate` try this

```
ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int position, long id) {
});
```

**OR** you can write this function which will handle the clicking on the list items

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {}
```

Comment: Thank you. I added onListItemClick with small 'OK' Toast message and the click is working (I get 'OK' toast message). BUT, list items doesn't change colour and blink when clicked (as they should). What could be wrong?

Comment: @1atera1us your question was about clicking on the list items, if you want about color please add more code and tell me exactly what color do you want and for which UI

Answer (score 0):

I have this working code, and I think in your Java code is the problem.

```
public class NewsListActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener
```

...

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(new NewsDataArrayAdapter(NewsListActivity.this, headlines));
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

...

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        if (v == null) {
            return;
        }
```

Comment: I am extending ListActivity, where I use onListItemClick.

Comment: @1atera1us would you try this WORKING solution?

Comment: I made my old solution working. But thank you, I will sure save this piece of code you provided.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(yourlistview);
Lv.setonItemClickListener(this);

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    paret.getItemAtPositon(position);
    //this returns you an object cast it into the same object you passed to your adapter cast to string if values passed were string
}
```